# How can i run some code at an exact timestamp?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a REST API in a backend with an array of objects with a timestamp (time when something happens in-game) and a value.

```
{"timestamp":1623320102097,"crops":[0,5,9]}
```

How can i do run something when time is equals to that timestamp ?

Answer (score 2):

I presume that timestamps are in msec. Probably this should do the trick:

```js
let diffMsec = obj.timestamp - new Date().getTime();
if (diffMsec > 0) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      /* do your stuff */
   }, diffMsec);
}
```

Keep in mind though, that [it is not guaranteed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays) that timeout will be invoked at the exact time.

Comment: Additionally, if the timestamp is a fair way in the future, it would be worth storing the result of `setTimeout`, in case it needs to be cancelled via `clearTimeout`